# Design approach for calling Stored Procedure from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, stored-procedures, architecture, microservices

I am working on transforming project from OLD one new one (Spring Boot,Angular). In old project they render data from Stored Procedure now I want to convert the logic to new one So what is the best approach to convert this in to Micro-service. 
  There are more than 100 Stored procedure so Can I call Stored Procedure as it is from REST api or can I bring Stored procedure logic in spring Boot (i.e. REST API) . 
   Which design pattern should I use while implement this ?

Please guide me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to extract all business logic and all logic not related to the datastore from the database, and place it in one or several services (microservices), depending on if this logic is related only to one single domain or more.

The reason to do that is to decouple your business logic from the way you store the data.

Doing it this way your services are stateless and can be scaled out as mucha as you need, and in addition to this, you can choose the datastore or datastores that bests suits your use-cases (fast writes, fast reads, time series analytics.. etc) without worrying the business logic

Comment: Thanks JArgente for your reply, any specific design patterns should I use while implementing this approach in Java?

Comment: To modularize your application, I would recommend you DDD (domain driven design) there are a lot of bibliography about this. And in short is a paradigm that tries to split all your business logic in different contexts to achive the maximum decoupling between your services. Obviously this technique match perfectly with microservices architecture

Comment: Thanks JArgente for your valuable Suggestions